# How to get the glowing effect in circular progress bar in android?

Tags: android

In my android app, I have made a circular progress bar but it had the flat color and I had tried every possible way to get a glowing effect in the circular progress bar.

[Like shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN7H8.jpg)

Comment: where is your image?

Comment: click on the link (Like shown in the image) to view the image in which I want the glow effect in circular progress bar